# Flask models .save() raises TypeError: _validate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'

Tags: python, flask, mongoengine

I tried to add a list to an attribute but when I tried to save the db it raises the exception below. Is there something wrong with my code? I previously modified the models to add new attribute saved_jadwal_ids. I thought it caused no problem as I've tried to set value to it before doing jadwal.save() and I could print the value. Do I actually need to make migrations or something? Thank you.

```
jadwal = Jadwal.objects(id=jadwal_id).first()

eventIds = []
# courses = data['jadwals']
courses = getCourses()

for course in courses:
    id = insert_event(calendar, course)
    eventIds.append(id)

jadwal.saved_jadwal_ids = eventIds

jadwal.save()
```

Jadwal.py:

```
class Jadwal(Document):
    user_id = ReferenceField('User')
    jadwals = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(JadwalData))
    created_at = DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    saved_jadwal_ids = ListField(StringField)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\anisha\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "c:\users\anisha\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "c:\users\anisha\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\flask_cors\extension.py", line 161, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "c:\users\anisha\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "c:\users\anisha\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "c:\users\anisha\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "c:\users\anisha\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\Anisha\RISTEK BISMILLAH\sunjadv2-server\app.py", line 631, in add_jadwal_to_calendar
    jadwal.save()
  File "c:\users\anisha\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\mongoengine\document.py", line 362, in save
    self.validate(clean=clean)
  File "c:\users\anisha\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\mongoengine\base\document.py", line 377, in validate
    field._validate(value)
  File "c:\users\anisha\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\mongoengine\base\fields.py", line 234, in _validate
    self.validate(value, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\anisha\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\mongoengine\fields.py", line 857, in validate
    super(ListField, self).validate(value)
  File "c:\users\anisha\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\mongoengine\base\fields.py", line 431, in validate
    self.field._validate(v)
TypeError: _validate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'
```

Answer (score 6):

Try replacing:

```
saved_jadwal_ids = ListField(StringField)
```

with:

```
saved_jadwal_ids = ListField(StringField())
```

I could reproduce and fix the error with this snippet:

```
from mongoengine import Document, StringField, ListField

class Example(Document):
    meta = {'collection': 'examples'}
    saved_jadwal_ids = ListField(StringField)  # should be StringField()

e = Example()
e.saved_jadwal_ids = ['not','ok']
e.save()

TypeError: _validate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'
```